# Найти значение в Json с помощью python

Tags: python, json, алгоритм, графы

Есть файл json с неизвестным количеством тегов. Необходимо доставать значения по определенному тегу, допустим "BD". Сколько тегов уровнями выше или ниже, неизвестно. Возможно ли это сделать? Пока что думаю в сторону рекурсивной функции

В Качестве теста пробовал писать такое:

```
def myprint(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            myprint(v)
            print(v)
        # else: print("{0}  : {1}".format(k,v))
myprint(json_test)
```

На вид рабочий, но дальше первого ключа k не уходит. Основная проблема в том, что в Json содержатся list, в которых содержатся dict и не получается пройтись именно по list.

```
{
   "A": "1",
   "B": [
         "C": "2",
         "D": "3",
         "E": "4",
         "F": "5",
         "G": "6",
         "H": {
            "J": "6",
            "K": "7"
         },
         "L": {
            "M": "8"
         },
         "N": {
            "O": {
               "P": "9",
               "R": "10",
               "Q": "11",
               "S": "12"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен алгоритм обхода графа. Например, DFS или BFS

Comment: @nomnoms12 Если я правильно понимаю, что DFS, что BFS работают только для двумерных графов. У меня же уровней может быть несколько десятков, а соответственно писать что-то вроде graph[0][1][2][3] и т.д. при неизвестном количестве уровней не представляется возможным

Comment: Кажется, Вы неправильно понимаете. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, хотя бы первый абзац из Википедии: [Поиск в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Поиск_в_глубину). Вам должен подойти этот алгоритм

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да, спросонья неверно понял. Вспомнил еще из университетского курса. Проблема теперь в другом, но алгоритм действительно должен подойти. Спасибо

Comment: Рад помочь. Но в чём тогда проблема? Вам ещё нужна помощь?

Comment: @nomnoms12 В данный момент проблема заключается в том, что при построении DFS алгоритма, он не заходит в следлующие словари выгруженного Json

Comment: Как выглядит json?

Comment: @EdwardGrachev В каком плане как выглядит?
{
   "A": "1",
   "B": {
         "C": "2",
         "D": "3",
         "E": "4",
         "F": "5",
         "G": "6",
         "H": {
            "J": "6",
            "K": "7"
         },
         "L": {
            "M": "8"
         },
         "N": {
            "O": {
               "P": "9",
               "R": "10",
               "Q": "11",
               "S": "12"
            }
        }
    }
}
примерно так, только с тысячи полей, но понятие о структуре можно сложить по этому куску.

Answer (score 1):

---

Обновлено

Мне стало интересно улучшить функцию и я ее переписал

Новый вариант:

```
import json


def json_pars(*, json_array: json, result_list: list = None, key: str) -> list:
    if result_list is None:
        result_list = []
    if isinstance(json_array, list):
        for i in json_array:
            json_pars(json_array=i, result_list=result_list, key=key)
    if isinstance(json_array, dict):
        for i in json_array.keys():
            array = json_array[i]
            if i == key:
                result_list.append(array)
            else:
                json_pars(json_array=array, result_list=result_list, key=key)
    return result_list


with open("test.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json_array = json.loads(file.read())

print(json_pars(json_array=json_array, key="TEST"))
```

Проверял на основе:

```
[
  {
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Christina Blackburn"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Eve Gilmore"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kelsey Cummings"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Lopez Hines! You have 9 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": [
      "asd",
      "asda",
      [
        "sad",
        [
          [
            {
              "TEST": "нашел"
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

---

Вот пример который будет иметь неограниченное количество вхождений.

Старый вариант кода

```
import json
a  = """
{
   "A": "1",
   "B": [{
         "C": "2",
         "D": "3",
         "E": "4",
         "F": "5",
         "G": "6",
         "H": {
            "J": "6",
            "K": "7"
         },
         "L": {
            "M": "8"
         },
         "N": {
            "O": {
               "P": "9",
               "R": "10",
               "Q": "11",
               "C": "12"
            }
        }
        
    },
    {
         "C": "2",
         "D": "3",
         "E": "4",
         "F": "5",
         "G": "6",
         "H": {
            "J": "6",
            "K": "7"
         },
         "L": {
            "M": "8"
         },
         "N": {
            "O": {
               "P": "9",
               "R": "10",
               "Q": "11",
               "C": "12"
            }
        }
        
    }]
  
}"""


def pars(a: json, result_list: list = None) -> list:
    if result_list is None:
        result_list = []
    for i in a.keys():
        if i == "C":
            result_list.append(a[i])
        elif isinstance(a[i], dict):
            pars(a[i], result_list)
        elif isinstance(a[i], list):
            for j in a[i]:
                pars(j, result_list)
    return result_list


print(pars(json.loads(a)))
```